# UIWindow as popover on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, popover, uiwindow

I'm trying to subclass a `UIWindow` and use it as a popover with push navigation (it will essentially be showing iPhone `UIViewController`s in an iPhone size popover on the iPad version). I've attached a subclassed `UINavigationController` as a property with the following overrides:

```
- (void)alterViewControllerFrame:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [viewController.view setFrame:currentKeyWindow.bounds];
}

- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers
{
    for(UIViewController *controller in viewControllers)[self alterViewControllerFrame:controller];
    [super setViewControllers:viewControllers];
}

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self alterViewControllerFrame:viewController];
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}
```

However, when I show the "popover", the added `UIViewController`'s bounds are the size of `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`. Is it possible to properly resize the view controllers, as their UI is being build programmatically and not through an `XIB`?

I would have hoped that using a `UIWindow` in combination with a `UINavigationController` would have been a very clean solution to my popover concept, but it seems to be very stuck on the concept of obeying the bounds of the physical screen.

**Is there a good way to use a `UIWindow` as a custom popover with navigation, or will I need to create a custom popover?**

Comment: the problem is the size of the UIWindow? try using this `[[MyWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);`

Comment: @BlueGene Sorry for the delay. I have sized the window exactly like that, yes.